# Using Chrome browser instead of InternetExplorer.Application

Tags: vba, google-chrome, internet-explorer, excel

I know how to work with Excel VBA and IE, but I would like to know if it's possible to work with Google Chrome, since I find it faster than IE.

Here's what I mean specifically:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Can I substitute this with something that will launch Chrome instead of IE?

Comment: Yes, as long as it is installed on your computer you can launch the URL in Chrome using the command line. You just won't be able to use it to parse the `.Document` like an `InternetExplorer.Application` object.

Comment: It is installed on my computer, but I need to use it to parse the .Document

So, there's no workaround to make that happen?

Comment: If you want something faster than an ie object, start looking at the XMLHTTP libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome does not provide a Visual Basic interface like Internet Explorer does, so you cannot access any of it's properties (e.g. `Document`). You can launch chrome at a specific address just by passing to the executable.

For example:

```
Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
Dim executable As String = Path.Combine(path, "Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")

Process.Start(executable, "http://google.com")
```

Comment: The question asks for a Browser-Object which can be remote-controlled by an API and not how to start Chrome.exe.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent resource library called Selenium that has VBA Wrappers. There's a very basic tutorial [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-firefox-or-chrome-with-vba-and-selenium/), though if you really want to get anything done the best starting point is the example spreadsheet [hosted here](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic).

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub test544()
  Dim chromePath As String
  chromePath = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
  Shell (chromePath & " -url http:google.ca")
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: The question asks for a Browser-Object which can be remote-controlled by an API and not how to start Chrome.exe.