# Create an object for Google chrome

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I want to use the below code for Google Chrome instead of IE.

```
Public Sub GetValueFromBrowser()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim myPoints As String

    url = "http://localhost:8080/xyz"
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
      .Visible = 0
      .navigate url
       While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
         DoEvents
       Wend
    End With

    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = ie.document

    myPoints = Trim(Doc.getElementsByName("points")(0).Value)
    Range("A1").Value = myPoints

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [selenium basic](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/) VBA wrapper instead (Assuming rest of your code is accurate)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetValueFromBrowser()
    'tools > references > selenium type library
    Dim d As chromedriver, myPoints As String

    Const URL As String = "http://localhost:8080/xyz"
    Set d = New chromedriver

    With d
        .Start
        .Get URL  
        myPoints = Trim$(.FindElementByName("points")(0).Value)
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = myPoints
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

After installing selenium basic you will need to add the selenium reference. Go VBE > Tools > References > Selenium Type library

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround is probably to use Shell as answered in this post:

[Using Chrome browser instead of InternetExplorer.Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018858/using-chrome-browser-instead-of-internetexplorer-application)

Basically in 2 steps:

1. Find the path of the `Chrome.exe` in your computer.
2. Get your URL.

Example to run Google search page on Chrome:

> ```
> Dim chromePath As String
> chromePath = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
> Shell (chromePath & " -url http:google.ca")
> ```

Comment: This is not at all a workaround because you don't explain how one can access the HTML DOM.