# Controlling chrome by pure VBA without any extra installation

Tags: vba

**I tried to use Microsoft's built-in API to be able to do it.**

*following...*

```
    Dim tp As String
    Dim chromePath As String
    tp = "Test"
    
    With CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.youtube.com/"
    Do While .busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        With .document
            .all("search_query").Value = tp
            .all("search-btn").Click
        End With
    End With
```

---

**I want to use Chrome to retain cookies for operation, but I cannot
find any effective method.**

```
  Dim chromePath As String
  chromePath = "C\...\chrome.exe"
  Shell (chromePath & " -url https://www.youtube.com/")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018858/using-chrome-browser-instead-of-internetexplorer-application sums it up pretty nicely. You can't.

Comment: ok i got that, thanks you!